# vsphere HA host monitoring

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Something I stil can't figure out is the optional HA setting : "Host Monitoring".

What if you ENABLE HA, but you DISABLE 'host monitoring" ?

How will HA be able to detect which host doesn't have a heartbeat?
And what could be the reason for enabling only HA, but not 'host monitoring'?

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: See here - http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2012/01/25/re-when-to-disable-ha-cc-hashmibilal